# Snowflake- creating external table by using pattern

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to create the external table(xyz) in snowflake by using pattern to load historical file from stage, there are multiple files and using following pattern to load the file name started with below

201802242300_5d80272d1abcd32cc7a981da083ed498.gz. ( Feb 24th 2018 file)

```
    Create external table xyz
    (
     samplecol1 varchar as (value:samplecol1::varchar),
     samplecol2 varchar as (value:samplecol2::varchar),
     date as to_date(substr(metadata$filename,1,8),yyyymmdd)
    )
    partition by (date)
    location = @snowflakestage.largetable
    pattern='.*/20180224.*[_].*.gz'
    file_format = (type = 'JSON');
```

it's executing successfully but not loading any data.   Is my pattern right to pick the file name listed above?

Comment: Why do you have a leading `/` in the pattern? I don't see it in your file name

Answer (score 0):

A good way to test patterns is via the [LIST](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/list.html) command as it takes the same PATTERN option.

thus for you:

```
LIST @snowflakestage.largetable pattern='.*/20180224.*[_].*.gz'
```

for example using the CitiBike example data, there are not parque files
so if you try load all files, you get errors.

```
create stage citibike.public.citibike_trips 
    url = 's3://snowflake-workshop-lab/citibike-trips';

list @citibike_trips;
```

| name |
| --- |
| s3://snowflake-workshop-lab/citibike-trips-parquet/2022/01/08/data_01a19496-0601-8b21-003d-9b03003c624a_3106_4_0.snappy.parquet |
| s3://snowflake-workshop-lab/citibike-trips-parquet/2022/01/09/data_01a19496-0601-8b21-003d-9b03003c624a_1906_6_0.snappy.parquet |
| s3://snowflake-workshop-lab/citibike-trips-parquet/2022/01/10/data_01a19496-0601-8b21-003d-9b03003c624a_2206_6_0.snappy.parquet |
| s3://snowflake-workshop-lab/citibike-trips/json/2013-06-01/data_01a304b5-0601-4bbe-0045-e8030021523e_005_7_0.json.gz |
| s3://snowflake-workshop-lab/citibike-trips/json/2013-06-01/data_01a304b5-0601-4bbe-0045-e8030021523e_005_7_1.json.gz |
| s3://snowflake-workshop-lab/citibike-trips/json/2013-06-01/data_01a304b5-0601-4bbe-0045-e8030021523e_005_7_2.json.gz |

So I played around till I found this pattern worked for the files I wanted.

```
list @citibike_trips pattern = '.*trips_.*csv.gz';
```